# Why is the default seed of `mt19937` 5489?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, mt19937

According to [the Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/rand.eng.mers), the value of `mt19937::default_seed` is `5489u`:

```cpp
static constexpr result_type default_seed = 5489u;
```

This seems very artificial.

Is there any (mathematical or theoretical) reason behind this?

Comment: Please note that your observation is just on the specific implementation that you are looking at. It's most likely not the same for all implementations.

Comment: @super: no, the default seed is specified in the standard https://eel.is/c++draft/rand.eng.mers

Comment: That seed, 5489, was already present in the original reference implementation by the inventors of the mersenne twister (with no explanation given).

Comment: In the [MT](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/m-mat/MT/ARTICLES/mt.pdf) paper, the default seed of `4357` is used.  Hmmm.  Interesting question, and why is it `5489` now.  I think only **Makoto Matsumoto** or **Takuji Nishimura** can answer this question.

Comment: The original reference implementation referred to by @harold is maybe this: [mt19937-64.c](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/mt19937-64.c).

Comment: Most likely, agreed.  I suspect the answer will be something like along the lines of typing something like "qwerty".  But maybe there's some special significance to the `5489` value, or that other value.  I would contact Makoto and/or Takuji and ask them.  (I don't think they frequent this Q&A site.)

Comment: There is nothing special about 4357 value, as stated in the original paper. In fact, it is common to seed the twister from current timestamp (or any other source of entropy), so it is unlikely that some seeds are special. The change from 4357 to 5489 is baffling though. Sounds like an artificial change. Maybe it was someone's joke, for future generations to waste time on it. :D

Comment: Is there a value you would not consider artificial?  Or is your question why there has to be a default seed at all?  Are you looking for a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing-up-my-sleeve_number ?

Comment: I was expecting to find something like Marin Mersenne's birthday is 5/4/89.  Alas, that isn't the case.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry I should have mentioned the reason in OP. By, "not artificial", I'd like to mean `0` or `1`, just because other C++ libraries related to random numbers use `0` or `1` (e.g. `default_random_engine::default_seed = 1u`). So maybe I should say "inconsistent" rather than "artificial".

Comment: It was chosen by a RNG.

Comment: BTW, Mersenne Twister is a bit clunky compared to more modern alternatives. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Disadvantages & https://www.pcg-random.org/other-rngs.html

Answer (score 20):

C++'s Mersenne Twister uses 5489 as the default seed value because of the many, many implementations which used it before.  That is, it's a tradition.  Just as one example which predates the C++ implementation by a long time, Matlab also uses 5489.

So it would be inconsistent to use 0 or 1, because those are not values used by other popular Mersenne Twister implementations.

There have been other values like 4357 used before 5489, see this thread for some details and links to those historical default seeds: https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/gsl-discuss/2006-q4/msg00014.html

5489 may have first been used in 2002, by this implementation from Nishimura and Matsumoto: http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/m-mat/MT/MT2002/CODES/mt19937ar.c

Finally, note that some simple integer seeds like these can put the Mersenne Twister into a relatively low entropy initial sequence.  I speculate that someone noticed (between 1998 and 2002) that 4357 caused such a problem and 5489 appeared to give better results.

Comment: This doesn’t explain *why* those numbers were chosen. Perhaps that’s a valid question for Crytography.SE?